# Difference between virtual and full patching of vulnerabilities?

Tags: vulnerability, patching

What is the difference between virtual patching and full patching of vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual patching tries to block the attack vectors, i.e. using some IDS, firewall or similar. But the vulnerability itself is still unfixed and if someone finds a new attack vector which bypasses current blocks the vulnerability can still be exploited.
Full patching instead fixes the vulnerability itself so it cannot be longer exploited by any attacker vector.

See also [OWASP: Virtual Patching Best Practices](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Virtual_Patching_Best_Practices).